# Optimizing Android shared preference value access

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am using Androids shared preferences as a simple Storage like this:

```
class Storage(context: Context) {
    private val storage = context.getSharedPreferences("my_storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    private val myKey = "my_string_key"

    fun getMyString(): String {
        return storage.getString(myKey, "default String") ?: "default String"
    }
    fun setMyString(str: String) {
        storage.edit().apply {
             putString(myKey, str)
             apply()
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't like how this introduces boilerplate code each time I add another stored value.

This is my current workaround:

```
class Storage(context: Context) {
    private val storage = context.getSharedPreferences("my_storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    private inline fun put(block: (SharedPreferences.Editor) -> Unit) {
        storage().edit().apply {
            block(this)
            apply()
        }
    }

    var myString: String = "default String"
        set(str) = put { it.putString(::myString.name, str) }
        get() = storage.getString(::myString.name, field) ?: field
}
```

Now my Questions are:

1. Is this even a good idea? (Im new to programming on the Android platform and I haven't seen anyone do this, so there might be a good reason to stick to the function approach)
2. Can this be optimised further? Ideally I would like to only declare the variable and have the getter and setter generated somehow.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not create a manager class and add all necessary getters and setters? What's wrong with that? If your project supports DI, you can inject the class into wherever you need it and that would simplify the overall flow.

Comment: @Jonathan Your approach is clean and smart. I do not see any issues with it

Answer (score 0):

I would choose different approach. You just need keys for this. For example something like this:

```
class Storage(context: Context) {
    private val storage = context.getSharedPreferences("my_storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    
    public fun getKey(key: String): String = storage.getString(key, "defaultString") ?: "defaultString"
    public  fun set(key: String, value: String) = storage.edit().putString(key, value)
    
    object Keys {
        const val key1 = "Key1"
        const val key2 = "Key2"
    }
}
```

Or, if you want more safety for keys to be used as constants, not strings

```
enum class Keys {
    key1, key2
}

class Storage(context: Context) {

    private fun getDefaultValue(key:Keys): String = when(key) {
        Keys.key1 -> "string"
        Keys.key2 -> "String2"
    }

    private val storage = context.getSharedPreferences("my_storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    public fun getKey(key: Keys): String =
        storage.getString(key.name, null) ?: getDefaultValue(key)

    public fun set(key: Keys, value: String) = storage.edit().putString(key.name, value)

}
```

Comment: I like your approach, but wouldn't that mean that all default Values are the same for all keys?

Comment: well, yes, in case that you have different default values, you could make string nullable and handle that in your code, or create some field    private val defaultValues = mapOf(
        Keys.key1.name to "defaultValue1",
        Keys.key2.name to "defaultValue2"
    )
and then cast use it like defaultValues.getValue(key.name) in getKey.

Comment: @JonathanS I made edit on second solution. Now I think it is clear, and easy. Added one method that will cover all Keys cases, and return different value for each. Notice that without else branch in when, every time you add new key, you will have to add default value, so it will be safe.